# How to get refreshed token from Google Calendar API

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

My goal is to retrieve events from google calendar in cron function, I need to do that without authorizing the requests every 1 hour since the access token expires. 
From many related stack overflow questions I understood that in the beginning I gain an access token from authorizing the request, then the token get written in a token.json file. After the first access, every time I need to access the calendar the function fGetClient control if the token is expired or not, IF I PREVIOUSLY SET

```
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

the function should refresh the token and i should access the calendar's event without authorizing any further request.

My problem is that i can't get the refreshed token, it expires in an hour and then i need to manually copy the link ,authorize the request and then copy and paste the verification code.

I leave the code below.

```
public function fGoogleCalendar($operazione=null){
        //require_once $this->config["googlecalendardir"].'vendor/autoload.php';

        // Get the API client and construct the service object.
        $client = $this->fGCGetClient();
        $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

        // Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
        $calendarId = 'primary';
        $optParams = array(
          'maxResults' => 10,
          'orderBy' => 'startTime',
          'singleEvents' => true,
          'timeMin' => date('c'),
        );
        $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
        $events = $results->getItems();

        if (empty($events)) {
            $aEventi="0 events found";
        } else {
            // "Upcoming events:\n";
            foreach ($events as $event) {
                $start = $event->start->dateTime;
                if (empty($start)) {
                    $start = $event->start->date;
                }
                $end = $event->end->dateTime;
                if (empty($end)) {
                    $end = $event->end->date;
                }
                
                $aEventi[]=array(
                            "nome" => $event->getSummary(),
                            "startdate" => $start,
                            "enddate" => $end 
                        );                          
                $start);
            }
        }
        return $aEventi;

    }

    public function fGCGetClient(){
        require_once $this->config["googlecalendardir"].'vendor/autoload.php';

        $client = new Google_Client(); 
        //die("ok");
        $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
        $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
        $client->setAuthConfig($this->config["googlecalendardir"].'credentials.json');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
         //$client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
        $client->setPrompt('consent');

        // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        $tokenPath = $this->config["googlecalendardir"].'token.json';
        if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
            $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        }

        // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
        //if (true) {
        if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
            if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                //$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken());
            } else {
                // Request authorization from the user.
                $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl(); 
                printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                print 'Enter verification code: ';
                $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                // Check to see if there was an error.
                if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                    throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                }
            }

             
            // Save the token to a file.
            if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
            }
            file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
        }
        return $client;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you follow [php quick start](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/php) you will notice that it request offline access this means that the first time the user authorizes this application that the refresh token will be returned its then stored in $tokenPath

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}

/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        } else {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}


// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'primary';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 10,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c'),
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see that the token is stored in tokenpath (which is the token.json file) but this doesn't stop the function from request the manual authentication everytime the token expires (every 1 hour). I just want to manually give the consent only ONE time and then let the function refresh the token by itself.

Comment: It wont if there is a valid refresh token in that file it will use the refresh token to request a new access token.  It wont request authorization again unless there is something wrong with your refresh token.   make sure you have a valid refresh token you can revoke the users access to ensure that you get one back.  PHP only returns a refresh token for the first time.

Comment: Okay, so I must check if the refresh token is valid... and how can I do that? Can't find anything related to this in the Calendar API docs.

Answer (score 0):

In your current directory delete this file `token.json`

> It's where the token is saved if you delete the file your program won't find the token therefore create a new token.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).